# How to make a calendar Grid in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I want to develop a feature which is similar to the Calendar view in Google Calendar. Can anyone give me a brief idea about how can I develop this?.

Also, I want a similar animation of moving an item within a grid check out the image attached for example[image: calendar view]

Comment: There are a couple dozen calendar widgets in [the Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=calendar). If none meet your needs, use them to learn how they chose to lay out their grids.

Comment: @CommonsWare most of the library that are present provides CalendarView similar to appCompat. however to achieve this seems a little bit tough

Comment: @CommonsWare should I use recyclerview to make this UI from scratch

Comment: That would be where I would start, though I am sure that there are other approaches that one could consider.